# Inner JOIN missing row

Tags: mysql, wordpress, inner-join

First I would like to mention I have limited skills when it comes to MYSQL an JOIN. However this is what I have and what I like to achieve:

I have the default WordPress tables and like to get a result with post_name, title, status and the meta_value from a certain meta key.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT
    wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_status, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN
    wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE (
        wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
    )
    AND wp_posts.post_type =  'my_post_type'
    AND (
        wp_posts.post_status
    IN (
        'my_status_1',  'my_status_2'
    )
)
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'my_meta_key'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID ASC
```

Everything works as expected when each post has a postmeta of 'my_meta_key'. But if the 'my_meta_key' is missing the post is not in the result.

I guess it' caused by the second INNER JOIN but as mentioned I have no idea what I should it replace it with.

I'm sure it's something simple

Comment: Consider: Using LEFT Join instead of INNER JOIN.  See following link for visual explanation of join types: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `AND wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'my_meta_key'`   to

```
INNER JOIN
    wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
```

Like this and change the INNER for a LEFT

```
    LEFT JOIN
        wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'my_meta_key')
```

If you put your condition in the "Where Clause"  The Left join will be "overwritten".
And I will add an advice. Dont use parenthesis when you dont really need it to keep your code easy to read.

Comment: I knew it was something different. Thanks! I can't except it yet cause you were to fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `INNER JOIN` on the `wp_postmeta` table to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
```

And move the `WHERE` filter for the `wp_postmeta` to the `JOIN` condition.

So your query will be:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_status, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'my_meta_key'
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
    AND wp_posts.post_type =  'my_post_type'
    AND wp_posts.post_status IN ('my_status_1',  'my_status_2')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID ASC
```

The `INNER JOIN` syntax will only return rows that match in both tables. So if you do not have a matching row, you will not get any result.  By changing that to a `LEFT JOIN`, you will return all rows even if there is not a matching row in the `wp_postmeta` table. If the row does not exist, then the values from the `wp_postmeta` table will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns

- all records from WP_Posts
- only those records with WP_TERM_RELATIONSHIPS
- only those records in wp_postmeta which a matching record in wp_posts.

*

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_title, 
  wp_posts.post_status, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
  ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
  ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
  AND wp_posts.post_type =  'my_post_type'
  AND wp_posts.post_statusIN ('my_status_1',  'my_status_2') 
  AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'my_meta_key' or wp_postmeta.meta_key is null)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID ASC
```

you need the is null otherwise records in wp_posts without wp_postmeta data will be excluded.